# Escaping ORDER BY clause

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

i need some help here.

I have this query:

```
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']) : 'title';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY $order ASC");
```

You can either order by title, date or author.

But if someone gives $order something else it goes:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\entries.php on line 20
```

How do I get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't treat column identifiers the same as string literals.  In your example, you could end up with SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY O\'Hare ASC
```

Which would result in a syntax error in any SQL parser.

I have a few tips:

1. Put your SQL into a variable, don't try to build it inside the call to `mysql_query()`.  If you use a variable, you can now inspect the SQL string, which makes errors like the above easier to catch.

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY $order ASC";
   // here you can log $sql, or output to Firebug, etc.
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   ```
2. Check that the return value does not indicate an error.  You need to check for error states, because they can occur for many reasons.

   ```
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   if ($query === false) {
     die(mysql_error());
   }
   ```
3. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for *strings* -- not column names, table names, SQL keywords, etc.  What I use instead is an associative array that maps the `$_GET` input to a valid column name, so I know it's safe.  This also allows you to use different values in your app parameters than the names of columns.

   ```
   $ordercolumns = array(
     "t" => "title",
     "d" => "date"
   );
   $order = "title"; // the default
   if (isset($_GET["order"]) && isset($ordercolumns[$_GET["order"]])) {
     $order = $ordercolumns[$_GET["order"]];
   }
   // now we know $order can only be 'title' or 'date', 
   // so there's no need to escape it.
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY $order ASC";
   ```

Comment: Great answer! I learned something new :) I will bookmark this ;P

Answer (score 7):

You cannot have something like `colu\'nname` in an order by clause -- which means `mysql_real_escape_string` is not the solution here.

Instead, you should check that `$order` actually contains the name of one of the columns of your table -- and not run the query if it doesn't.

For example, you could use something like this :

```
if (!in_array($_GET['order'], array('column1', 'title', 'id', 'other_column'))) {
    // deal with the problem
    // and don't run the query
    // because $_GET['order'] is not one of the allowed values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just not offer any order options to the user, that doesn't. If you are using a text input, replace it with a select. As long as the column exists, you shouldn't get an error.

You might hardcode each option in a switch-case:

```
switch($_GET['order']){
    case 'date' : 
         $order = 'date';
         break;
    case 'author' : 
         $order = 'author';
         break;
    default
         $order = 'title';
}
```

That will also prevent SQL-Injections.

Answer (score 0):

It expects a column name in $order and if it isn't one it will fail. Try echoing the $query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the value of $_GET['order'] from a possible acceptable list of values.

You should also be checking if ($query) to determine if the query worked, before trying to fetch a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checker = array('title', 'date', 'author')

$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']) : 'title';

if (in_array($_GET['order'], $checker) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY $order ASC");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for valid values and present an error to the user if something isn't as you expect.

A simple example,

```
$valid_values = array("title", "date", "author");

if (in_array($_GET['order'], $valid_values))
{
    // Your db stuff
}
else
{
    echo "The order value you gave wasn't valid. Please try another.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure `$_GET["order"]` contains a valid column.
Your problem comes from getting an invalid column name, that you put in the query. The `mysql_query()` function return `false` on error, and your error message tells you passed it to a `mysql_fetch_assoc` call.

Try something like

```
$columns = array("id", "name", "title");
if (false === ($key = array_search($_GET["column"], $columns))) {
  $column = "title";
} else {
  $column = $columns[$key];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY {$column};";
```

I didn't use `mysql_real_escape_string` because this method also checks the input to be in the list of valid options.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see $order is a column name before you run the query

```
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']) : 'title';
//Run a check here, before the query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY $order ASC");
```

The mysql_real_escape_string also looks to be in an improper location. Just a heads up

Comment: This code doesn't do any checking if the column name is valid...

Comment: I was just showing the OP where to do the checking. After you set the var and before you attempt a query...